# Algebraic decision trees and adversary arguments

Tags: lower-bounds, decision-trees

In the comparison tree model, we establish lower bounds on computing
$\min$ and $\max$ of $n$ numbers via the adversary argument. Are there problems
on which we know lower bounds in the algebraic decision tree model via the
adversary argument? Please suggest relevant references.

Comment: Of course there are lots of other problems on which we can show lower bounds in comparison trees using adversary argument. But I haven't seen any lower bound using adversary argument in the algebraic decision tree model.

Comment: Also, the lower bound you have pointed to is via a topological argument and not via an adversary game.

Comment: What about linear decision trees, namely, decision trees in which nodes are linear equations over GF(2)? These have exponential size lower bounds using an "adversary" argument. That is, a game between a Prover and a Delayed. Cf. Impagliazzo/Pudlak 2001, and Itsykson/Sokolov 2014.